# A Zero divisor of an induced section

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, dg.differential-geometry, complex-geometry, algebraic-curves, vector-bundles

Let $f:X\rightarrow Y$ be a smooth family of complex projective curves on a smooth curve $Y,$ with singular fibers over some finite set of $Y.$ Let $\mathcal{A}$ and $\mathcal{B}$ are invertible sheaves (of positive degree, effective) on $Y$ and $\mathcal{A}\otimes\mathcal{B} \subseteq f_{*}\mathcal{C}$(subsheaf), where $\mathcal{C}$ is a locally free sheaf on $X,$ such that $\mathcal{C}\otimes f^{*}\mathcal{A}^{-1}$ has a global section $s$ with a zero divisor $D.$ Is there a section $t$ of $\mathcal{C}\otimes f^{*}\mathcal{A}^{-1}\otimes f^{*}\mathcal{B}^{-1}$ such that it has for a zero divisor again $D?$ 
Remark: since $\text{deg }\mathcal{B}^{-1}<0$ it has no a global nowhere zero section.

Comment: What do you mean by $f^*\mathcal{C}^{-1}$ if $\mathcal{C}$ is a sheaf on the source of $f$?

Comment: Pullback functor makes a sheaf on $X$ from a sheaf on $Y$, so what do you mean by applying this functor to a sheaf on $X$?

Comment: Sorry I see now the mistake...I will edit it

Comment: When you say that $\mathcal{C} \otimes f^* \mathcal{A}^{-1}$ has section $s$ with zero divisor $D$, does this mean it is a line bundle, i.e. $\mathcal{C}$ has rank 1? If so, the line bundle $\mathcal{C} \otimes f^* \mathcal{A}^{-1} \otimes f^* \mathcal{B}^{-1}$ cannot have a section with the same zero divisor, unless the line bundles coincide, i.e. $f^* \mathcal{B}^{-1} = \mathcal{O}$. Or am I misunderstanding something here?